# ActiveRecord - How to know if a field exists on another table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I want to update the `status` in the winners table into trues if a user with same mail id is signed up. I'm stuck with active record.

## schema.rb

```
   create_table "winners", force: :cascade do |t|
     t.string   "name"
     t.string   "email"
     t.string   "phonenumber"
     t.boolean  "status",      default: false
     t.datetime "created_at",                  null: false
     t.datetime "updated_at",                  null: false
   end
```

## table 2

```
   create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
     t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
     t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
     t.string   "nickname"
     t.string   "image"
     t.integer  "score",                  default: 0
   end
```

## model/user.rb

```
    after_create :update_status
    def update_status
     #if self[:email] = #any mail in winners table
      #update the corresponding winners row with status.
     if Winners.where(email = :email)
     update attributes

    end
```

How to make such queries with active record?

Comment: u can try this.
`def update_status
     winner = Winner.where("email = ?", self.email).first 
     unless winner.blank? #any mail in winners table
        winner.status = true # Or false
        winner.save!
     end
   end`

Comment: @AmitSharma, if you feel your method will solve his problem, please write it as an answer instead of a comment. Method written in comment section is not readable.

Comment: @AmitSharma that's true, It will be great if you can post this answer section.

Comment: @user121212 is your Winners table contains multiple entries for same email address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it with an after_create hook in your **model/user.rb:**

```
after_create :update_status

def update_status
  Winner.where(:email => self.email).each do |winner|
    winner.status = true
    winner.save
  end
end
```

You might argue updating winners based on a user signing up should be a controller task, not the models though. I am a friend of explicitly calling stuff in your controller, instead of letting it happen automagically. That's more a thing of personal taste though, this should be perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, I hope this will help you.

In **model/user.rb**

```
after_create :update_status

def update_status
  #update the corresponding winners row with status.
  winner = Winner.where("email = ?", self.email).first
  unless winner.blank
    winner.status = true  # Or false
    winner.save! # Or If You want to skip validation then use winner.save(validate: false)
  end
end
```